# Getting different instance of class variable when calling getter in another node

Tags: c#, godot

I am getting a strange error where when I call the getter for the bool "Extended" in my node "Dragon" inside of the node "player", I believe I am getting a different instance of the variable than the one inside of "Dragon". I am correctly getting the instance for the Dragon class, as other methods work fine.

I am changing the variable here within the class Dragon.cs:

```cs
if (this.DragonNeck.GlobalPosition.DistanceTo(this.Player.GlobalPosition) < 100f)
{
  this.Extended = true;
}
```

This is being called by ::_Process

I initialize the variable at the top of the class like so:

```cs
public bool Extended { get; set; }
```

I then get the instance of Dragon in my "player" class:

```cs
public override void _Ready()
{
  this.Dragon = (Dragon)this.GetParent().FindChild("Dragon");
}
```

I finally access the variable from the player class:

```cs
private void _on_offering_area_body_entered(Node2D body)
    {
        this.Dragon.Expand(1.1f);
        GD.Print(this.Dragon.Extended);
        if (body.Name != "PlayerCharacter" || this.FoodItems == 0 || this.Dragon.Extended) {return;}
        Console.WriteLine("Weight - " + FoodItems);
        CurrentWeight -= FoodItems;
        this.Dragon.Expand(1.1f);
        FoodItems = 0;
    }
```

The printout stays false, even when the variable is being updated inside of the Dragon class. I have printed out the variable in the Dragon class and it is updating there. And I can confirm that the Dragon is the same as ::Expand() is working fine. The hashcodes for the dragon `GD.Print(this.Dragon.GetHashCode())` and inside of Dragon `GD.Print(this.GetHashCode())` print the same number.

Is something being cached in the background of Godot? I am very stumped.

Edit:
When accessing the variable in ::_Process() in the "player" class. I get the correct variable. Though, even if I assign this to a class variable in player. It will not update in _on_offering_area_body_entered(Node2D body) context.

Edit:
Found a fix, though I'm still a bit confused why I get multiple calls to the _on_offering_area_body_entered(Node2D body) and the variable does not update with the current version.

Fix:

```cs
public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
        if (this.Entered)
        {
            GD.Print(this.Dragon.Extended);
            if (this.FoodItems == 0 || this.Dragon.Extended) {return;}
            Console.WriteLine("Weight - " + FoodItems);
            CurrentWeight -= FoodItems;
            this.Dragon.Expand(1.1f);
            FoodItems = 0;
        }
    }

    private void _on_offering_area_body_entered(Node2D body)
    {
        if (body.Name.Equals("PlayerCharacter"))
        {
            this.Entered = true;
        }
    }

    private void _on_offering_area_body_exited(Node2D body)
    {
        if (body.Name.Equals("PlayerCharacter"))
        {
            this.Entered = false;
        }
    }
```